# How to switch between two different 3 monitor setups?

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, tv

I am currently working on a fun idea. My current desktop setup has a triple monitor setup, but I had an idea of connecting my TV to my desktop, to have a console like experience without actually purchasing a console. I have grown quite fond of playing on my TV like this, but it is just such a hassle disconnecting my main monitor from desktop to connect my TV. From what I can see I need a HDMI splitter for this purpose.

However, I like having Discord and some streaming service showing while playing, so I was thinking of getting two cheap monitors that I could flip out from behind my TV, that should also be connected to my desktop.

But how would I connect them? Would I need 3 different splitters for that? I would really like if I could with at push of a button switch between the two different setups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you might want to look into is HDMI Multiplexer devices. There are quite a few "2 input 1 output" type devices, but there are also "Matrix" devices that allow you to switch multiple outputs like [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07SWJG2DY) this one that allow you to take in some signals and switch them between outputs.

That specific device would be able to switch an input between two outputs. Granted you would need one for each output of your computer, but they're not shockingly expensive and are more convenient than messing around with cabling.

Search for terms like "HDMI 1 in 2 out" or "HDMI 4x4" (4in 4 out) for devices that can take in more signals and output them to more monitors. Just be aware that they will get progressively more expensive the more inputs and outputs you are switching.